# ¿ como se puede hacer filter entre 2 modelos por un campo en común y contar los datos filtrados?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Tengo este código como ejemplo, pero aun no comprendo, como hacer el llamado de 2 modelos, para poder filtrar los datos y contarlos.

```
A.objects.filter(B__is_available=True).annotate(num_b=Count('b')).filter(num_b__gt=0).order_by('-num_items')
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es el problema?, ¿no funciona?, ¿te arroja un error?

Answer (score 0):

Este seria el modelo 1

## Informacion Usuario

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='userprofile')
tipo = models.CharField('Tipo de Usuario', choices=settings.TIPO_USUARIO_CHOICES, null=True, max_length=20)
fecha_expiracion = models.DateField('Fecha Expiracion', null=False, blank=False, default=tz_now)
perfil_riesgo = models.CharField('Perfil de Riesgo', choices=settings.PERFIL_RIESGO_CHOICES, null=True, max_length=10, blank=True, default="AE", editable=False)
riesgo = models.IntegerField('Riesgo', null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
monto_evolucion = models.IntegerField('Monto Evolucion', null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
```

Este es el modelo 2

```
class GCMClient(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField('Id', primary_key=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='usuario_gcm')
registration_id = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField(max_length=200)
tipo = models.CharField('Tipo', default="GCM", max_length=3)
fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField('Fecha de Creacion', null=False, blank=False, default=tz_now)
```

Necesito hacer un filter con esos modelos, de forma que compare los campos user de ambos modelos, que la fecha de expiracion del usuario sea mayor a la de hoy y contar el id.

Como ejemplo de lo que estuve haciendo es esto:

```
app_premium_activo_android = GCMClient.objects.filter(user__UserProfile__tipo="premium", fecha_expiracion__gte=tz_now()).count()
```