# Necesito hacer un filtro entre 2 modelos

Tags: django, django-models, djangorestframework

Modelo 1

```
 class Respuesta(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField('id', primary_key=True)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, null=True, blank=True, 
    related_name='respuesta_categoria')
    nombre = models.CharField('Nombre', max_length=100)
    respuesta = models.TextField('Respuesta Pre Diseñada')
    fecha = models.DateTimeField('Fecha', auto_now_add=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Modelo 2

```
 class Mensaje(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField('id', primary_key=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='UsuarioFyFMensaje')
    consulta = models.ForeignKey(Consulta, related_name='ConsultaFyF')
    fecha = models.DateTimeField('Fecha', auto_now_add=True)
    texto = models.TextField('Texto')
    archivo_adjunto = models.URLField('Archivo Adjunto', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    msg = models.TextField('Mensaje')
    respuesta = models.ForeignKey(Respuesta, related_name='respuestaMensaje', null=True, blank=True)
    calificacion = models.SmallIntegerField('Calificacion de la respuesta', default=0)
```

filtro

```
Respuesta.objects.filter(consulta__Mensaje=id).count()
```

Necesito contar todas las consultas del mensaje, que tenga el id de respuesta

Comment: Hola, realizaste anteriormente la  misma pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/180232/quiero-hacer-filter-entre-2-modelos-por-un-campo-en-com%C3%BAn-y-contar-los-datos-fil incluso otra relacionada, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/179993/como-se-puede-hacer-filter-entre-2-modelos-por-un-campo-en-com%C3%BAn-y-contar-los , te sugiero evitar esta práctica, realiza una pregunta basada en [ask], saludos.

Comment: verifica [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/227744/buscar-por-foreign-key-drf/227760#227760)